# How to apply Dijkstra algorithm to my adjacency graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra, minimum-spanning-tree, adjacency-list

i have a programming assignment that require me to build an adjacency graph and applied Dijkstra algorithm to find a MST. I have build my adjacency graph, but i dont know how to apply the Pseudo-code for the Dijkstra algorithm. 
The link had the code for adjacency list, http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/CS3343/newgraph/graphrep.html

The Pseudo-code for the Dijkstra algorithm:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcOs8.png

Is there anyway to applied the Dijkstra algorithm for this graph?
Thank you very much!!

Comment: *Is there anyway to applied the Dijkstra algorithm for this graph?* If it doesn't have negative weights, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply pseudo code you typically code it up in some language and then run the code.